# Evenly distributing duplicated strings among several lists using R

Tags: string, r, distribution

So let's say I have a character vector of length 150000. Strings in the vector are not unique, in fact they're sorta normally distributed  with the most frequent string being present 28 times, another 24, and over 1000 present more than 5 times. I want to divide the vector into 28 smaller vectors, distributing the strings among the smaller vectors such that no string is present more than twice in each smaller vector, ideally only once (or not present). I need to preserve every string, so I can't just do `!duplicated()` Ideally the vectors would be about the same size.

How the heck would I do this?

I'm thinking something like start adding to the first vector until you encounter the first non-unique string, skip it, continue filling skipping non-unique strings until you've reached 150000/28 = 5357, then proceed through the other vectors the same way, removing strings from the parent vector once they've been allocated to a smaller one? Any issues with this? Efficient ways of doing it without a nasty forest of for loops?

Comment: Edited to clarify the vectors should be about the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed like a pretty interesting problem, although maybe it only seemed interesting because I misunderstood it- the solution I've got here creates `length of character vector / frequency of most frequent item` sub vectors, and then puts each string into `f` of those sub-vectors, where `f` is that string's frequency. This is possibly more complicated than what you were actually asking for.

```
library(plyr)
# I created a file with 10000 random strings and a roughly similar frequency 
# distribution using python, and now I can't remember exactly what I did
strings <- read.csv("random_strings.txt", header=FALSE,
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)$V1
freq_table <- table(strings)

num_sub_vectors <- max(freq_table)
# Create a list of empty character vectors
split_list <- alply(1:num_sub_vectors, 1, function(x) return(character(0)))
for (s in names(freq_table)) {
  # Put each string into f of the sub-vectors, where f is the string's 
  # frequency
  freq <- freq_table[[s]]
  # Choose f random indexes to put this string into
  sub_vecs <- sample(1:num_sub_vectors, freq)
  for (sub in sub_vecs) {
    split_list[[sub]] <- c(split_list[[sub]], s)
  }
}
```

To test that it's worked, pick a string, `s` or a frequency `f`, and check that `s` occurs in `f` of the sub vectors. Repeat until you're confident.

```
> head(freq_table[freq_table==15])
strings
ad ak bj cg cl cy 
15 15 15 15 15 15 
> sum(sapply(split_list, function(x) "ad" %in% x))
[1] 15
```

Comment: It is a bit more complicated that I was thinking. I'm just trying to split the strings roughly evenly across the partitions without having repeats of a string in any one subvector, so the sum of the lengths of the subvectors should equal the length of the original, and they should ideally be the same size, with a little remainder in one.

Comment: I think this solution fits most of those requirements, except for all of them being the same size- my answer ends up with most of the sub-vectors being roughly the same in length, but not identical.

Comment: I also think your requirements might be trickier to completely satisfy than you think they are- the maximum length of any single vector is `u` the number of unique elements in your original vector, but if any of your strings have a frequency of 1, then the rest of the vectors now have a max length `u - 1`, and as you use up the low frequency strings, that maximum keeps decreasing, so you end up with shorter sub vectors- I can't really see a way around that for the moment.

Comment: So the above solution seems to double the frequency of the strings across the whole set. For example. a string that's present 4 times in the original vector will be placed in 8 subvectors, a string that's present once in the original will occur in two subvectors, etc and I don't immediately see what that should happen. Did you intend this to happen? The best solution would not increase the aggregate number of strings across all vectors.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought that's what I was testing with `sum(sapply(split_list, function(x) "ad" %in% x))`- how are you testing that? Another alternative is `sum(sapply(split_list, function(x) length(x[x == "ad"])))`, but that seems to work fine for me as well.

Comment: I'm using the sapply formula you gave above. So I've ended up with 28 lists of lengths ranging from about 8500 - 8700. So I now have 243020 strings when the original vector had 157283. This means that not every string is being duplicated, but many are. The length of the vectors should be about 5600.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas, every test I can think to run on my example data seems to check out. You can find which strings are being duplicated with `sapply(split_list, function(x) x[duplicated(x)])`, but unless you notice something unusual about them or their frequencies, I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: I figured out what happened. I started the loop, stopped it to add a printout to indicate how long the code would run for, and neglected to re-initialize split_list, so I was just appending to the previous run. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

This meets your requirements (each string only once per subvector) fairly concisely by just tallying how often each string occurs and then partitioning based on "strings that appear i or more times":

```
inputs <- c("foo", "bar", "baz", "bar", "baz", "bar", "bar")
histo <- table(inputs)
lapply(1:max(histo), function(i) { names(histo)[histo>=i] }
```

This will of course yield partitions of wildly varying sizes, but you're not very clear on what your requirements in that area are.

Comment: (1) I suppose the user is looking for vectors of equal length. (2) The object `results` is of no use. (3) Your example doesn't reflect the condition of the question, i.e., the length of the original vector is a multiple of the maximum number of occurrences of the most frequent string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't specify the length of the vectors, because it's not that important, but I am trying to keep them roughly equal in size.